# How do AWS Direct connect and VPC peering differ ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc, aws-direct-connect

Can someone help me understand the basic difference between AWS direct connect and VPC peering.

Answer (score 5):

AWS VPC Peering is connection between two AWS VPC networks (even between accounts) . Easy as that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html

AWS Direct Connect is used to connect on-premise datacenter through dedicated line (you can imagine it as private internet). As far I understod AWS  has separate connections to number of partner providers around their datacenters.

https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/partners/